# TYPO3 extension update DCE 1.1 to 1.2 - rte fields are missing

Tags: typo3, tx-dce

I have updated the extension DCE from 1.0.4 to 1.2.5 as described in https://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-dce/wiki/Updating-DCE-from-version-below-12#Updating-DCE-from-versions-below-12 (TYPO3 6.2).

After updating all field which are rte-fields named "text" are missing in backend and also in frontend no text ist shown. but in database the text is still available, because if I add once more the text-field, the rte-field is shown in backend and text is also shown in frontend.

Has somebody an idea what went wrong?

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. Update script is writing wrong value for field parent_dce. This happend to those dce elements, which I had copied. So ID was double and update-script wrote wrong id to database.

So I manually changed the ID to correct ID of dce-element and set new fields to copied dce elements.